# Non messy way to randomly set a variable, and unset the rest?

Tags: bash, variables, random

Let's say I have 5 variables in Bash:

```
foo
bar
goo
var
dog
```

I want to randomly pick ONE of these variables, set it to "1", and unset the rest of the variables to nothing, or 0, whichever.

I can definitely think of a way to do this with shuf, but it's going to be very un-elegant, and I was hoping to do this with more than 5 variables. I'd like to see what you fellow people think of that won't be as a mess as what I envision doing.

Comment: *clever*?  Really?  Do you mean obscure?  Convoluted?  Me, I go for **simple** every time.  KISS.  How much time is wasted on trying to understand "clever" code.  If you can think of an obvious way to do it that works, go for it.

Comment: I mean it as not being overly messy. Sorry if that was vague

Comment: Randomly zapping variables sounds like a crazy thing to want to do.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Choose a random transition for a video since it will allow me only one. I'd also like to pick only the ones that are set beforehand, so it can randomize between only the ones that have been manually set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it.  It might be the same as yours, who knows since you have kept it to yourself.  I use an array and the dreaded `eval`.  Please note that `eval` can be a security risk if you set values that have come from an external source.

```
foo='Foo'
bar='Bar'
goo='Goo'
var='Var'
dog='Dog'

tmp=(foo bar goo var dog)

idx=$(( $RANDOM  % ${#tmp[@]} ))
count=0
for ele in "${tmp[@]}"
do
    if (( count == idx ))
    then
        eval "$ele=1"
    else 
        eval "$ele=0"
    fi
    (( count++ ))
done

echo "$foo, $bar, $goo, $var, $dog"
```

EDIT, possibly simpler:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo='Foo'
bar='Bar'
goo='Goo'
var='Var'
dog='Dog'

tmp=(foo bar goo var dog)

idx=$(( $RANDOM  % ${#tmp[@]} ))
for (( ele=0; ele < ${#tmp[@]}; ele++ ))
do
    if (( ele == idx ))
    then
        eval "${tmp[$ele]}=1"
    else 
        eval "${tmp[$ele]}=0"
    fi
done

echo "$foo, $bar, $goo, $var, $dog"
```

Edit: Possibly simplest(bonus no eval)  From @123:

```
tmp=(foo bar goo var dog)

idx=$(( $RANDOM  % ${#tmp[@]} ))
count=0
for ele in "${tmp[@]}"
do
    (( $ele = count++ == idx))
done

echo "$foo, $bar, $goo, $var, $dog"
```

`$ele = count++ == idx` required explanation.  Normally we do not supply `$` on the left in an assignment, but in this case (`$ele =`) the substitution is done early and give us the desired effect.  The `count == idx` returns 1 on equality and 0 on failure to the left (opposite of conditionals in the shell).  `count++` is a *postfix* operator and increments *after* the rest of the statement.

Comment: I added a solution to the bottom, it was to long for a comment and too similar to yours to warrant another answer, feel free to remove it if you feel it is incorrect.

Comment: @123:  THAT is very good.  It should be in an answer under your name, I shouldn't take credit for it.  I think a comment is required though.

Comment: @123 I agree with cdarke. Your solution is the best so far.

Comment: @cdarke It's fine, I'm not really bothered about being credited. Good explanation as well :)

Comment: @123 Glad to have learned to set a variable to another other than the eval and let commands. This one is my favorite since it's the only one without eval. Still trying to grasp the `count++` part. Thank you cdarke and 123.

Comment: @TuxForLife You may be suprised to know that `(())` is in fact the `let` command!

Comment: Now looking back, I do recall seeing it in a Bash tutorial long, long ago, but I personally never thought I'd get this advanced in it. I definitely wouldn't have remembered, so yes in fact I am surprised!

Answer (score 2):

Simple example using bash built-in variable `$RANDOM`

```
#!/bin/bash

foo='Foo'
bar='Bar'
goo='Goo'
var='Var'
dog='Dog'

declare -a RANDOM_ARRAY=( foo bar goo var dog )

for ((i=0; i<${#RANDOM_ARRAY[@]}; i++));
do
    eval "${RANDOM_ARRAY[$i]}=0"
done

echo -e "$foo $bar $goo $var $dog"

# Using bash built-in'$RANDOM' variable to randomize the element
# between 0 and 32767

RANDOM_ELEMENT=$[ $RANDOM % 5]
eval "${RANDOM_ARRAY[$RANDOM_ELEMENT]}=1"

# Optional to print this

echo -e "$foo $bar $goo $var $dog"
```

Run multiple trials to observe the randomization.

Comment: Where do you set the variables?  You appear to only be setting the elements in the array, not the variables themselves.

Comment: You are still only setting the array, not the stand-alone variables as in the question.

Comment: Echo the variables, `$foo`, `$bar`, `$goo`, etc.  at the end of your program.  You have not changed those, you only change the array.

Comment: Don't use `$[ ... ]`; it's not even documented anymore. Use `$(( ... ))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like this:

```
myvars=(var_a var_b var_c)
index=$(($RANDOM % ${#myvars[@]}))

for var in "${myvars[@]}"
  do if [[ "${var}" == "${myvars[$index]}" ]]
        then eval "${var}=1"
        else eval "${var}=0"
  fi
  echo ${var}=${!var}
done
```